# Duplicate column definition name provided

Tags: angular, angular-material

I create this table :

```
<table
    mat-table
    *ngIf="selectedActors.length > 0"
    [dataSource]="selectedActors"
>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="picture">
        <td mat-cell *matColumnDef="let element">
            <img [src]="element.picture" alt="" />
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <td mat-cell *matColumnDef="let element">
            {{ element.name }}
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="character">
        <td mat-cell *matColumnDef="let element">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Character : </mat-label>
                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="element.character">
            </mat-form-field>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
        <td mat-cell *matColumnDef="let element">
            <mat-icon mat-list-icon (click)="remove(element)"></mat-icon>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay"></tr>
</table>
```

this is my columnsToDisplay variable :

```
columnsToDisplay = ['picture', 'name', 'character', 'actions'];
```

I get this error in my console :

> Error: Duplicate column definition name provided: "undefined".

Comment: Is `<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">` not *matColumnCell, see the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)

Comment: provide data for selectedActors